# Sending email through client side, without opening the email client window

Tags: javascript, html, email, extjs, client-side

On my client side, whenever, user presses the submit button, I want the email to be sent to a userAdmin. I do not want the user who is clicking the submit button, to be aware of this, & neither the email client should get open. I want to implement this on client side. I looked into the

```
mailto:
```

but that is not something interested in, as it opens the mail client up. Any idea how to achieve this using HTML5, Javascript, ExtJS 4.1.3?

Comment: *"I do not want the user who is clicking the submit button, to be aware of this..."* Red. Flag.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:  Consider it as a notification for the userAdmin...

Comment: @ unix_user: That's fine. Do it server-side. (That's your only choice anyway.) Seriously, consider the ramifications if web pages could be written such that sending in a form generated an email **from the client computer**. Spammers and such would absolutely love it. You don't need a botnet! Just use this web page... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I was fearing for the security, but thought could add some layers of protection to it.... Can you point me a good way to do it server side...

Comment: @ unix_user: You have your pick of (probably literally) a couple of hundred different ways, depending on your server-side stack. Once the data is on the server and the server is responding to it, your options are wide open. PHP, Java, C#, Ruby, C (via CGI)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks a lot for this...i see similar questions on this in stackoverflow, seems it involves a lot of hack to achieve this on client side...i think i can manage to do it using ajax and c# processing...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to implement this on client side.

You can't. The only way to do what you've described, without the user being aware of it, would be to have the submit button actually send a form (e.g., the normal thing they do), and have server-side code send the email. This cannot be done client-side without user involvement. Which is how it should be.

Comment: Ok, considering the user does know about it, still is there a way that the email client does not get open.... Is there a way that the email gets sent directly.. The value of sender and receiver in the email is a hard code value, and not going to  change..

Comment: @unix_user: I don't believe so, no. You can open the client and pre-fill those addresses, but the user will have to actually send the message.